# where is (0,0) when animation relates `Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF`?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

Where is (0,0) when using this method?

```
public static void slideTooltip(final LinearLayout toolTipLayout) {

    TranslateAnimation layoutTranslateAnimation =
        new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0F, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0F,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 2.0F, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0F);

    layoutTranslateAnimation.setDuration(10 * 1000);
    layoutTranslateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    // layoutTranslateAnimation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

    final AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.2F, 1.0F);
    alphaAnimation.setDuration(10 * 1000);

    toolTipLayout.startAnimation(layoutTranslateAnimation);
  }
```

Is it it the top-left of the window?

Is it the top-left of the view?